# What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array for future anomalies. This error keeps popping up. What's the problem? I've used the same code before for a larger array, tried to shorten it and now its got lots of errors.

```
import numpy as np
import csv

    emptystns=[]
    with open('stationlist2.tsv') as i:
    j = csv.reader(i, delimiter='\t')
    next (j)
    for r in j:
        emptystns.append(r[0]) 



    lines = []

    ns = sum(1 for line in open('stationlist2.tsv'))-1
        #3660 stations (minus the headerline which is not a stationid)
    nmons = 12
        #12 months in a year
    nlays = 8
        #the number of depths in layers is the number of layers
    stnslist= []

    data=np.ma.masked_all((ns, nlays, nmons), dtype=np.float64)  

    with open ('SoilAverage1981.tsv', 'r') as f:
    reader= csv.reader(f,delimiter = '\t')
    next(reader)

    for line in reader:
        temp = line[2:]
        istn= emptystns.index(line[0])
        ilayers = line[1]

        for i, info in enumerate(temp):                         
            imonth = i
            if info !='':
                data[istn, ilayers, imonth] = info

print 'done'
```

Error message:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),     numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: What's the full error with trace?

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is. Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: error should show you which line makes problem so use `print()` to check values in variables. It seems you use `None` as index. Maybe some variable has value `None` and you have to find where it get this value.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make an educated guess, since there only seems to be one place where you are indexing a numpy array:

```
data[istn, ilayers, imonth]
```

Look at `data`, checking its `shape` and `dtype`.

Look at the indices, `istn`, `ilayers`, `imonth`. Is any not in the list provided by the error?  May be a string, maybe a float number or list?

```
integers, 
slices (`:`), 
ellipsis (`...`),     
numpy.newaxis (`None`) 
integer or boolean arrays
```

The basics to debugging an error like this:

- identify where the error occurs
- identify all the variables in the expression
- verify the identify and/or properties of those variables
- which one(s) match the error message or fail to match documented behavior.